# bash to remove file in directory if search string found in another file

Tags: bash

The `bash` below is almost complete. The only part I am struggling with is that in the `process.log` if the string `The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason.` is found then the corresponding `.bam` (`$f`) in the `bash`, is removed. I added:

```
echo "The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason."
             [[ -f "$f" ]] && rm -f "$f"
```

in an attempt to do this, but it looks like it is removing the last `.bam` regardless (in the process.log NA19240.bam (that file has the search string in it), but it was not. Instead the last `.bam` (`NS12911`) in the process.log is (even though the search string is not there).  I am not able to fix this and need some expert help. I apologize for the lengthy post, just trying to add all the details.  Thank you :).

**bash**

```
logfile=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/process.log
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/*.bam ; do
 echo "Start bam validation creation: $(date) - File: $f"
 bname=`basename $f`
 pref=${bname%%.bam}
 bam validate --in $f --verbose 2> /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/${pref}_validation.txt
 echo "End bam validation creation: $(date) - File: $f"
done >> "$logfile"
for file in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/*.txt ; do
 echo "Start verifying $(date) - File: $file"
 bname=`basename $file`
 if $(grep -iq "(SUCCESS)" "${file}"); then
    echo "The verification of the bam file has completed sucessfully."
else
    echo "The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason."
             [[ -f "$f" ]] && rm -f "$f"
    echo "End of bam file verification: $(date) - File: ${file}"
fi
done >> "$logfile"
```

**process.log**

```
 Start bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:20:48 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA12878.bam
 End bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA12878.bam
 Start bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA19240.bam
 End bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA19240.bam
 Start bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NS12911.bam
 End bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NS12911.bam
 Start verifying Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA12878_validation.txt
 The verification of the bam file has completed successfully.
 End of bam file verification: Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA12878_validation.txt
 Start verifying Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA19240_validation.txt
 The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason.
 End of bam file verification: Fri May  6 13:28:05 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA19240_validation.txt
 Start verifying Fri May  6 13:28:05 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NS12911_validation.txt
 The verification of the bam file has completed successfully.
 End of bam file verification: Fri May  6 13:28:05 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NS12911_validation.txt
```

Comment: May be you want to carefully look at where you use what variable, `$f` vs. `$file`?

Comment: `$f` is the original `.bam` and `$file` is the `.txt` that has the search string in it. If the search string is found in `$file` then `$f` is removed. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is is a little hard for me to completely replicate your environment so I am having to make some assumptions about your setup and exactly what your constraints are. I see many ways the process could be simplified or made more efficient but instead of introducing to many unneeded changes, I mainly focused on making the script work.

With that said, I did rearranged the processing to where each `${pref}_validation.txt` is verified right after it is created.

Can you try the following (**note: Updated the script. First time around I got going a little too fast and copied the wrong version.**) and let me know what the result is:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/process.log"

for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/*.bam ; do
    echo "Start bam validation creation: $(date) - File: $f"
    bname="$(basename "$f")"
    pref="${bname%%.bam}"
    bam validate --in "$f" --verbose 2> "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/${pref}_validation.txt"
    echo "End bam validation creation: $(date) - File: $f"

    file="/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/${pref}_validation.txt"

    echo "Start verifying $(date) - File: $file"

    if grep -iq "(SUCCESS)" "${file}"; then
        echo "The verification of the bam file has completed sucessfully."
    else
        if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
            rm -f "$f"
            echo "The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason."
        fi
    fi

    echo "End of bam file verification: $(date) - File: ${file}"

done >> "$logfile"
```

Hopefully combining the two steps in the one for loop does not deviate from some process requirement you have. What I find helpful about it is that it allows for a more streamlined code flow and the log file should now read like:

```
Start bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:20:48 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA12878.bam
End bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA12878.bam
Start verifying Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA12878_validation.txt
The verification of the bam file has completed successfully.
End of bam file verification: Fri May  6 13:28:03 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/bam_validation/NA12878_validation.txt
Start bam validation creation: Fri May  6 13:24:15 CDT 2016 - File: /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016/NA19240.bam
...
```

---

**Highly Modified Version**
I took a try at the highly streamlined and more resilient version of the script. I would be interested if you could check this one as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

# basepath allows you to quickly move the script by updating this path
basepath="/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/5-4-2016"

# give the logfile a name
logfile="${basepath}/process.log"

# for each .bam file in basepath do
for f in ${basepath}/*.bam ; do

    # validate the file with the bam command
    # capture the stdout, stderr and return code via some crazy bash fu
    eval "$({ cmd_err=$({ cmd_out=$( \
        bam validate --in "$f" --verbose \
      ); cmd_rtn=$?; } 2>&1; declare -p cmd_out cmd_rtn >&2); declare -p cmd_err; } 2>&1)"

    # check the return code for positive completion
    if [ "${cmd_ret}" -eq "0" ]; then
        printf -- "%s - bam validation completed for: %s\n" "$(date)" "${f}"

        # check for string "(SUCCESS)" in bam command standard output 
        if grep -iq "(SUCCESS)" <<< "${cmd_out}"; then
            printf -- "%s - Verification of the bam file has completed sucessfully.\n" "$(date)"
        else
            # verify the bam file exists and can be deleted
            if [[ -f "$f" ]] && rm -f "$f" ; then
                printf -- "%s - The bam file is corrupted and has been removed, please check log for reason.\n" "$(date)"
            else
                printf -- "%s - WARNING: The bam file is corrupted but the file could not be deleted.\n" "$(date)"
            fi
        fi
    else
        # The bam validate command above did not complete with a
        # satisfactory result. This should not really ever happen unless
        # the bam command does not exist or some serious error occurred
        # when executing the bam command.
        # Consider addition actions in addition to logging the outcome
        printf -- "%s - WARNING: bam validation failed for file: %s - [%s]\n" "$(date)" "${f}" "${cmd_err}"
    fi

done >> "$logfile"
```